# Spark-submit yarn-client mode hangs even though spark task completed (pyspark 3.4.1)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Recently set up a dockerized env along with CDP for submitting yarn-client mode spark jobs on a kereberized hadoop cluster and seeing inconsistent behavior with application lifecycle. Scenario:

- Docker container running on CONTAINER_HOST acts as driver for yarn-client mode submission.
- App is submitted with below params where CONTAINER_HOST is hostname where the docker image is running. Notice custom ports due to firewall. all ports are forwarded on the HOST machine so no issues with connectivity.(notice bunch of confs mostly for performance and network. performance or memory issues cannot be reason because smaller jobs work fine and below also succeeds at times but not always) :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
            --conf spark.driver.host=${CONTAINER_HOST} \
            --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=${IP_OF_DOCKER_CONTAINER} \
            --conf spark.ui.port=4000 \
            --conf spark.driver.port=5000 \
            --conf spark.blockManager.port=6000 \
            --name sample_yarnclient_job \
            --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 \
            --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=3600 \
            --conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 \
            --conf spark.executor.metrics.pollingInterval=10000 \
            --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=3s \
            --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC \
            --conf spark.network.timeout=50000s \
            --conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 \
            --conf spark.yarn.am.memory=12g \
            --conf spark.yarn.am.cores=2 \
            --conf spark.yarn.tags=sample_yarnclient_job \
            --conf spark.network.timeout=50000s \
            --conf spark.yarn.historyServer.allowTracking=true \
            --conf spark.ui.filters=org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnProxyRedirectFilter \
            --driver-cores 1 \
            --driver-memory 6g \
            --executor-memory 6g \
            --executor-cores 5 \
            --num-executors 24 \
            main.py
```

- Long running Application would start and progress can be seen from spark UI through the <CONTAINER_HOST>:4000 (forwarded port from container) but process at the end would randomly hang after the df.write operation. Looking at the Hadoop DEBUG logs, client logs would show below:

```
23/11/20 13:04:47 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1542521250) connection to nn01/nn01_ip:8032 from xyz@HADOOP.CORP.ORG sending #1687 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB.getApplicationReport
23/11/20 13:04:47 DEBUG DataStreamer: DFSClient seqno: 196 reply: SUCCESS reply: SUCCESS reply: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 540810 flag: 0 flag: 0 flag: 0
23/11/20 13:04:47 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1542521250) connection to nn01/nn01_ip:8032 from xyz@HADOOP.CORP.ORG got value #1687
23/11/20 13:04:47 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine2: Call: getApplicationReport took 80ms
2023-11-20 13:04:48,308 - sample_yarnclient_job - INFO - duration  : 0:15:31.523891
23/11/20 13:04:48 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DFSClient: WriteChunk allocating new packet seqno=197, src=/user/spark/spark3ApplicationHistory/application_1698068797292_95503.inprogress, packetSize=65016, chunksPerPacket=126, bytesCurBlock=8302592, output stream=DFSOutputStream:blk_1826745110_753447846
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient flush():  bytesCurBlock=8302986, lastFlushOffset=8302920, createNewBlock=false
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DataStreamer: Queued packet seqno: 197 offsetInBlock: 8302592 lastPacketInBlock: false lastByteOffsetInBlock: 8302986, blk_1826745110_753447846
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DataStreamer: blk_1826745110_753447846 waiting for ack for: 197
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DataStreamer: stage=DATA_STREAMING, blk_1826745110_753447846
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DataStreamer: blk_1826745110_753447846 sending packet seqno: 197 offsetInBlock: 8302592 lastPacketInBlock: false lastByteOffsetInBlock: 8302986
23/11/20 13:04:48 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://${CONTAINER_HOST}:4000
23/11/20 13:04:48 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
23/11/20 13:04:48 DEBUG DataStreamer: DFSClient seqno: 197 reply: SUCCESS reply: SUCCESS reply: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 615921 flag: 0 flag: 0 flag: 0
23/11/20 13:05:03 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1542521250) connection to nn01/nn01_ip:8020 from xyz@HADOOP.CORP.ORG sending #1688 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.renewLease
23/11/20 13:05:04 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1542521250) connection to nn01/nn01_ip:8020 from xyz@HADOOP.CORP.ORG got value #1688
23/11/20 13:05:04 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine2: Call: renewLease took 81ms
```

- Log clearly says, context is closed (df.write completed and data is good) and Spark UI has stopped at (23/11/20 13:04:48 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.) however, there seems to be no activity for the next few minutes (approx 15mins) on Application Master and eventually shows FAILED.
  YARN APP MASTER LOG:

```
Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:322)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:572)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:954)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:953)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:953)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:985)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to ${CONTAINER_HOST}/${CONTAINER_HOST_IP}:5000
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: ${CONTAINER_HOST}/${CONTAINER_HOST_IP}:5000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Spark driver client log ends with below:

```
23/11/20 13:21:14 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/11/20 13:21:14 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/11/20 13:21:14 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/11/20 13:21:14 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/11/20 13:21:14 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/11/20 13:21:14 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
2023-11-20 13:21:15,466 - py4j.clientserver - INFO - Closing down clientserver connection
23/11/20 13:21:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/11/20 13:21:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ff1daff9-df2a-48ea-b44d-c476d35f4eef
23/11/20 13:21:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-0c48487d-899b-42f7-bb8d-37d2c818d81f
23/11/20 13:21:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-0c48487d-899b-42f7-bb8d-37d2c818d81f/pyspark-4a03ec68-9b0e-44ae-81ea-e3624033408f
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG FileSystem: FileSystem.close() by method: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.close(DistributedFileSystem.java:1518)); Key: (XYZ@HADOOP.CORP.ORG (auth:KERBEROS))@hdfs://hdfs-nn; URI: hdfs://hdfs-nn; Object Identity Hash: 4b9c2d62
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG Client: stopping client from cache: Client-84992557b3564a11bb507901c1debcf6
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG FileSystem: FileSystem.close() by method: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.close(FilterFileSystem.java:529)); Key: (XYZ@HADOOP.CORP.ORG (auth:KERBEROS))@file://; URI: file:///; Object Identity Hash: 4efa9988
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG FileSystem: FileSystem.close() by method: org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.close(RawLocalFileSystem.java:759)); Key: null; URI: file:///; Object Identity Hash: 6a37064a
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG FileSystem: FileSystem.close() by method: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.close(DistributedFileSystem.java:1518)); Key: (XYZ@HADOOP.CORP.ORG (auth:KERBEROS))@hdfs://hdfs-nn; URI: hdfs://hdfs-nn; Object Identity Hash: 34c414e2
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG Client: stopping client from cache: Client-84992557b3564a11bb507901c1debcf6
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG ShutdownHookManager: Completed shutdown in 0.015 seconds; Timeouts: 0
23/11/20 13:21:15 DEBUG ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHookManager completed shutdown.
```

Pyspark invoke as suggested [Do I need to stop spark after creating sparksession using pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773515/do-i-need-to-stop-spark-after-creating-sparksession-using-pyspark) :

```
def main() -> None:
    spark_conf = {'spark.logConf': 'true'}

    with create_session('sample_yarnclient_job', **spark_conf):
        SparkContext.getOrCreate().setLogLevel("ERROR")
        start_time: datetime = datetime.now()

        some_df_operation(df)

    end_time: datetime = datetime.now()

    LOGGER.info(f'duration  : {end_time - start_time}')
```

(Hostnames and IP has been substituted for privacy)
Tried many different network timeout and heartbeat parameters but nothing seems to fix this completely. Can someone help or share what could be possible reason for this? I understand the spark UI will no longer show once sparkSession is closed but why does the application master lose connection with driver and eventually fails with error even though all tasks completed as per History?